# Google analytics, php api, request time

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

At the moment i have a full implementation of google analytics in my web client.
Also i managed to track api calls in my backend php api.
But i was searching a lot about how to track more information than the api call.
I mean, i would like to know if there is any way to get information beyond the number of request as i can do with the js api.
Im specially interested in how to track the time the api takes to give the response as i can do for example with the time that the web client takes to get a response.

I tried searching in the ga documentation but i didnt find anything.

Maybe its something that is not supported, but if there is any way to achieve that i would like to know.

Please give some tips.

Thank you!

Comment: You _can_ get that data by querying for metrics. `ga:pageLoadTime` is one such metric https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=site_speed&jump=ga_pageloadtime

Comment: you could also try https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#timing

Comment: Hello and thanks!
I need something like this, but i dont have a browser.
I need a piece of code to put in muy backend api that tracks the api response time and sends it to ga as i do in my web application.

Comment: If you want to measure things like that, Google Tag Manager is something worth looking into. It makes it easy to create custom events that fire on any kind of event you want (ex: link click, page click, etc). You can also add your own custom javascript to google tag manager that will measure performance of anything you can possibly track.

Comment: The main problem is that i dont have any javascript because its only a php api, no client side application.
Also, i need to have these data in the ga platform so i cannot use another api or service.